# Voice controlled lights

Tags: lighting, home-automation

I currently have Ge Cync Bulbs with Alexa voice commands control them via my Echo Dot. they're connected to a dumb switch and are hubless smart bulbs. They have to be constantly powered so my light switch is permanently in the on position. Is there a way I can wire my lights up so that they're still powered but I don't need the light switch anymore?

Comment: I like to keep them switched and always on so that if the wifi is out i can still turn them off.

Answer (score 1):

You need power to the electronics, so no; if the switch isn't on, there's nothing the bulb can do. The obvious answer is to move to smart switches (always powered) and dumb bulbs.

Or bypass the switch as @crip659 noted, but that's going to annoy guests who have no idea how to turn your lights on and off, and locks you into paying the surcharge for "smarts" in the bulbs every time you replace them.

I have exactly one smart bulb, and that's because for that application I needed a color-changing bulb. Everything else is smart switches/dimmers.

Comment: Just wondering if code has caught up to voice/smart light bulbs and still require light/s in a room to be controlled by a light switch?

Comment: There is nothing for code to "catch up" to. Light controls on the wall are required in very specific places for good reason. It doesn't matter whether they're dumb/wired, smart RF, or something else. Having the only lights in a room controlled exclusively by voice, app, roaming remote control, etc. will never be acceptable to code.

Comment: I should note that no one would but me would be in my room as it is my bedroom

Answer (score 1):

To be code compliant (unless you have another light switch near an entrance that will turn a light on manually) you need a <s>switch</s> listed wall mounted control device. When the fire or ambulance folks show up they need to be able to turn on a light.

210.70(A)(1)

You can use an open-sided switch cover to allow switch operation while reducing or eliminating inadvertent switch operation. I presume the code language change to "listed wall mounted control device" from "switch" is to permit things like a wireless remote that will turn on a "smart" light.

Wall mounted occupancy sensors are permitted if they are in addition to a wall switch, or mounted in a customery wall switch location and have a manual override that will permit them to act as a switch built into them.

Comment: So in other words there's no easy way to do this without hiring an electrician who would be able to do this while being compliant with code.

Comment: Depends on what you consider easy. Also depends on if you rent (yes, electrician is required, non-optional) or own (in most, but not all, jurisdictions a homeowner, but NOT a renter, can do switch wiring.)

Answer (score 0):

By turning off the breaker,you can connect the two wires on the switch together and remove the switch.

The box is now just a simple junction box and has to remain on the wall with a blank face plate.

Removing the switch box will require a rewiring of the wires.

EDIT  I might have spoken/answered too soon.  It is possible that electric code, that at least one light in a room, must be controlled by a light switch by the door(so you do not step on a lego block in the dark).  If so, you cannot remove the wall switch or change the switch as @keshlam suggested in his answer.

Not sure how this will work, if the light switch can only turn off the light/stop it from working.  If you turn off the light switch, but if the light comes on, when the switch is turned on again, you will probably need to keep it.

If the light will only turn on with voice, then it will be iffy for the inspectors, if you need the switch there.

Comment: I think the box th bulbs came in might have come with one of these https://www.gelighting.com/smart-home/light-switches-remotes/wire-free-switches If I bypass the dumb switch and connect that to the bulb I can then have a physical switch i can just keep in my nighstand draw and pull it out when I need to. The code says you need at least one physical switch it doesn't say it has to be attached to the wall.

Comment: @Anon  I do not think that is the way it works.  I think code requires a switch by the door/enterence of a room.  Mainly for the use of fire/EMTs after you stepped on a lego block in the dark.

Comment: In fact, code says it DOES need to be a: "Listed, **wall mounted** control device" As already stated in my answer, a week ago. Hidden in a drawer will not do. If the supplied device is listed, (meaning by UL or ETL or another Nationally Recognized Testing Laboratory) and it can be wall-mounted, that can be your required control. But not if you keep it in a drawer.